# Access FTP Hosted Web API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ftp

I have created a Web API in ASP.NET. I deployed this API in Azure Web App and I was able to use controllers from web API like this http://.azurewebsites.net/api/{controller}.

Now I have deployed the Web API on an FTP server and I am unable to access my controllers like I did before. Any idea on how to do it?

I would really appreciate your help as I am new to FTP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you deploy it via FTP, exactly? What kind of web-host did you deploy to? Is the right version of ASP.NET correctly installed + configured on it?

Comment: You can't host a webapi on an ftp server. That's like trying to print out your code and host your webapi in a library. You must deploy it to an asp.net server.

Comment: I used Visual Studio deployment wizard to deploy my web api. What would I need to deploy this web service onto my own windows server.

Comment: Is your windows server running IIS? If so, you would have to create an IIS Site first then point the FTP upload to the folder where the new site is. On the other hand, is probably easier if you use the IIS publish option inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can upload/deploy an asp.net site via FTP, it does not mean that the server can automatically run the site and start serving those endpoints (/api/{controller}) automatically.

You need to clarify with whoever is hosting your FTP server if such server can also host asp.net websites. If so, you need to ask them in what particular folder within that server you need to upload your site to.

Comment: In the case of IIS and ASP.NET it isn't as simple as knowing what directory is the website root, you may also need to configure "application scopes" which can only be done by editing `applicationHost.config` which is not usually accessible to shared web-hosting customers.